# Want to open a dialog box to open file in web browser based application

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Am using JSF and primefaces to develop web application.I want to open existing files on client machines using dialog box which prompts the user to select a path and the corresponding file. Please suggest a component which can be used.

Comment: the file should be opened using default program of the given filetype?

Comment: The file is already existing on the client machine and the client wants to open the existing file using a file open dialog.File can be of any format.How can it be done?

Comment: What would be the expected behavior when you open an `.odf` or a `.doc` file on the client machine, using your file open dialog?

Comment: A file open dialog is opened and the user double clicks a file of his choice and the corresponding file is opened.For example a .doc file will be opened in MS Word.

Comment: Am already getting the filepath of the specified file but cannot open the file.How can it be done?

For example am getting the path D:\abc\filename.txt but need some component to open the same.

Answer (score 0):

While I doubt the feasibility of your intentions; accessing content directly on a client's machine (some security implications there), a combination of [`<p:media/>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/media.jsf) and [`<p:lightBox/>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightBox.jsf) will work for you. There are file type restrictions imposed  by primefaces though (multimedia files and pdf only) The `<p:media/>` can be embedded in the `<p:lightBox/>` like so :

```
    <p:lightBox>
          <p:media value="{yourBean.filePath}" width="100%" height="300px">
    </p:lightBox>
```

Like I said, I doubt the feasibility of directly streaming content from a client's local filesystem. How do you intend to use the path `c:\Users\john doe\my documents\my books\book.pdf` on a user's local system within your own web application, without first uploading the file to your own webserver? With image files, you might have some success loading the file into memory and streaming the file directly from RAM using [`<p:dynaImage/>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf)...consider the scalability of this option too for a high traffic application